# Replace in dataframe the '%' and then convert all the strings to float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select, lambda

I have data in *.csv with these headers:

> locationA_hhs locationA_hhs_ratio locationB_hhs   locationB_hhs_ratio locationC_hhs   locationC_hhs_ratio locationD_hhs   locationD_hhs_ratio

Here's one row of the content of this file:

> 16    0.52%   19  0.88%   14  0.46%   17  0.29%

I need to read-in only the percentages as float. 
Assuming I have read in the *.csv into a data-frame, I' am trying to select only the column-names ending with 'ratio', replacing the '%' with '' and then converting all those columns to type float. But this code doesn't yield that result. 
Please help!

```
df_raw.select(lambda col: col.endswith('ratio'), axis=1).replace('%','').astype(float)
```

Answer (score 2):

`replace(X)` replaces the *full value* `X`, not a part of the value. You have to use the `regex=True` option:

```
result = df_raw.loc[:, df.columns.str.endswith('_ratio')]\
               .replace('%', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a double percent sign `%%` to prevent it from being interpreted so you can print an actual `%` sign:

As following Example:

```
test = "have it break."
selectiveEscape = "Print percent %% in sentence and not %s" % test
print selectiveEscape

Print percent % in sentence and not have it break.
```